# How can I use span like table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this HTML structure:

```css
.subject{
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <span class = "subject">Name:</span>
        <span class="content">John</span>
</div>
<div>
        <span class = "subject">Age:</span>
        <span class="content">23</span>
</div>
<div>
        <span class="subject">cell phone:</span>
        <span class="content">+9400321532</span>
</div>
```

As you see, those columns aren't in the same line. I want this output:

```
/*
Name:       John
Age:        23
cell phone: +9400321532
```

How can I do that?

Actually I need a fixed-width for `span.subject` the size of biggest content length which is `cell phone` in this case.

---

Here is my code in reality:

```css
.notifications_list{
 margin-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 direction: rtl;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.notifications_list li{
 list-style: none;
}
.notification_date_title{
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.note_icon{
}

.note_icon i{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.note_type{
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="notifications_list">
  <div class="notification_date_title">امروز +5</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">2 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">دیروز +10</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">14 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">در هفته گذشته </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span class="note_type">تایید جواب</span><span class="note_date_time">2 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">3 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what the end UI needs to look like.

Comment: @z0mBi3 I want this http://i.stack.imgur.com/wV0IB.png

Comment: @MartinAJ How does the screenshot differ from what you have now?

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: table-cell;`

```css
.subject {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
}

div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="subject">Name:</span>
  <span class="content">John</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="subject">Age:</span>
  <span class="content">23</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="subject">cell phone:</span>
  <span class="content">+9400321532</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, But `display: table-cell;` doesn't work for me, I've edited my question and I added my real HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to make `span` as table

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, But `display: table-cell;` doesn't work for me, I've edited my question and I added my real HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of display table-row and table-cell to achieve this. Below code you can see that the width of the longest content is taken as the width if not it will take a min-width of 50px;

Hope this is what you are expecting :

```css
.notifications_list{
 margin-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 direction: rtl;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.notifications_list div, .notifications_list ul{
  display: table-row;
}

.notifications_list li{
 list-style: none;
}
.notification_date_title{
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.note_icon{
}

.note_icon i{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.note_type{
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="notifications_list">
  <div class="notification_date_title">امروز +5</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">2 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">دیروز +10</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">14 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">در هفته گذشته </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span class="note_type">تایید جواب</span><span class="note_date_time">2 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">3 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, But `display: table-cell;` doesn't work for me, I've edited my question and I added my real HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
.subject{
  width: 82px;   
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, But `display: table-cell;` doesn't work for me, I've edited my question and I added my real HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```css
.subject{
    width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
.content{width: 50%;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <span class = "subject">Name:</span>
        <span class="content">John</span>
</div>
<div>
        <span class = "subject">Age:</span>
        <span class="content">23</span>
</div>
<div>
        <span class="subject">cell phone:</span>
        <span class="content">+9400321532</span>
</div>
```